# Cannot convert value of type 'NSObject -> () -> PostFeed' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I'm adding a `UISwitch` in the following way:

```
  let anonSwitch : UISwitch = {
   let mySwitch = UISwitch()
    mySwitch.on = false
    mySwitch.setOn(false, animated: false);
    mySwitch.tintColor = UIColor(red: (69/255.0), green: (209/255.0), blue: (153/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
    mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAnonSwitch), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    return mySwitch
}()
```

Now I'm getting the following error message on the `self` keyword in `mySwitch.addTarget` :

```
 Cannot convert value of type 'NSObject -> () -> PostFeed' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'
```

I use `self` in all my other `addTarget` functions for `UIButton` and I never encounter this error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change your `let` into a `lazy var`.

I'm not sure exactly what the compiler is thinking (or where its crazy error message is coming from), but my guess is this:

In Swift, variables which are `let` have to be initialized before you can use `self`. One reason for this is that the compiler can't verify that `addTarget(action:forControlEvents:)` isn't going to try to call `anonSwitch()` on whatever it gets for `target`, or do something else, like access a different variable that would be initialized after `anonSwitch`, that depends on initialization having completed for this object.

Using `lazy var` means that the compiler can verify that the value assigned to `anonSwitch` won't be accessed before `self` is a valid object, because it won't be possible to call `anonSwitch` until all other members of the class have been initialized.