# UISwitch. Segmentation fault: 11 with swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiswitch

In my app I would like to use UISwitch inside tableview cell. When I try to add target to my custom switch I got an error: "Segmentation fault: 11". The code is down below. How can I fix this?

```
let cellSwitch: UISwitch = {
    let cellSwitch = UISwitch()
    cellSwitch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cellSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSwitch(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    return cellSwitch
}()

func handleSwitch(_ mySwitch: UISwitch) {
    if mySwitch.isOn {
        print("On")
    } else {
        print("Off")
    }
}
```

Comment: I am wondering if there wasn't any compile error.

Comment: When I try build the project it fields with the error "
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crashing with *Segmentation fault: 11* is a bug of Swift compiler, and you should send a bug report to Apple or swift.org.

And in Swift 3, some sorts of bug in your code often triggers this compiler bug.

In your case, you cannot use `self` in the initial value of an instance property. One way to work this around is using `lazy`:

```
lazy private(set) var cellSwitch: UISwitch = {
    let cellSwitch = UISwitch()
    cellSwitch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cellSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSwitch(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    return cellSwitch
}()
```

Another way is moving the assignment to `cellSwitch` to somewhere `self` is available. (Inside the `viewDidLoad()` maybe.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgot to add your cellSwitch to the tableview cell. This could cause the issue about `addTarget` to `self`.

Answer (score 0):

I typed your code and compiled in Xcode 7.3 and this line caused an error.

```
cellSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSwitch(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

So I changed cell switch declaration from `let` to `lazy var` in order to compile the code without an error. ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37636341/5657370) is good explanation why this causes compile error) But I think this may not what you want to do. You can just add UISwitch in your custom tableViewCell as an IBOutlet property and move your addTarget action code in your viewController.